# Como checar se há algum string repetido em uma lista?

Tags: python-3.x

Gostaria de aprender uma maneira mais fácil de checar todos items em uma lista
e procurar por strings repetidos.

Atualmente estou fazendo desta forma:

```
elif "azul" in fios[0] and fios[1] or "azul" in fios[1] and fios[2] or "azul" in fios[0] and fios[2]:
    print("Corte o último fio azul")
```

Minha intenção é checar se há mais de um "azul" dentro da lista fios,
o código está funcionando, mas gostaria de torná-lo mais pratico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta você utilizar o método [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) do objeto `list`:

```
cores = ['azul', 'amarelo', 'vermelho', 'preto']

print(cores.count('azul'))  # 1

cores = ['azul', 'amarelo', 'vermelho', 'azul']

print(cores.count('azul'))  # 2
```

Comment: elif fios.count("azul") is >= 2:               ficou certo?

Comment: Não tem o operador `is`, apenas o `>=`